# VirtualHost won't allow two domains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

This is my VirtualHost file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backendtwo/
ServerName www.designer-school.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName www.joshhornby.co.uk

</VirtualHost>
```

joshhornby.co.uk is the root directory and the reason I am adding this is because after adding the first VirtualHost for designer-school.com any url on joshhornby such as joshhornby.co.uk/typewriter stops working. I can't access my blog posts either, try it out for your self joshhornby.co.uk is the address. The blog address are permalinked like this
http://joshhornby.co.uk/post/web-course

As you can see this returns a 404.

My question is how can I serve two websites on the same server which doesn't stop one website from working as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `NameVirtualHost *` instead of `*:80`

The reason for the behavior you described, requesting joshhornby.co.uk opens the first one, is that `NameVirtualHost *:80` will match the first `VirtualHost *:80` definition.

If you use just `NameVirtualHost *`, then you're telling apache to search all `VirtualHost` definitions to find the best match, instead of the first positive match.

Comment: There's no change in the search behavior between `*` and `*:80` - both will search for a matching `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`, and only fall back to the first defined if no match is found.

Answer (score 2):

You should use NameVirtualHosts.

Put a

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

before your vhost configurations.

Comment: See edit to how my httpd.conf looks now. joshhornby.co.uk now loads up designer-school.com for some reason!

Comment: Actually it should be `NameVirtualHost *`